# Manipulate local variable inside the reactive map and return end result only

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-webflux, reactive-programming

I was developing logic to calculate the summary details and return it after going through some db operations. It was like this

```
@Override
    public Mono<ResponseEntity<?>> generateSummary(Locale local) throws Exception {
        Summary summary = new Summary();

        return test1Repository.findBySession("test").map(session -> {

            return test2Repository.findAllById(session.getListOfObject()).map(data -> {

                if(condition){
                    **Logic to update the summary object
                }
                if(condition){
                    **Logic to update the summary object
                }
                return summary;
            });
        }).map(result -> ResponseEntity.ok(result));
    }
```

```
public class Summary {
    private AtomicInteger disconnectCount;
    private AtomicInteger connectCount;
}
```

As a result, I get the list of Summary objects based on the `session.getListOfObject()` count. Something like this

```
[
    {
        "disconnectCount": 1,
        "connectCount": 1,
    },
    {
        "disconnectCount": 1,
        "connectCount": 1,
    },
    {
        "disconnectCount": 1,
        "connectCount": 1,
    }
]
```

But I wanted to return one single Summary object after doing all the manipulations. How do I achieve this behavior in Java reactive environment? Maybe Im not returning it correctly but I'm not sure

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. *map* operation transform input elements one by one, and return as much elements as the input. In your case, you want to perform a *reduction* operation, i.e use [reduce](https://projectreactor.io/docs/core/release/api/reactor/core/publisher/Flux.html#reduce-java.util.function.BiFunction-) or [reduceWith](https://projectreactor.io/docs/core/release/api/reactor/core/publisher/Flux.html#reduceWith-java.util.function.Supplier-java.util.function.BiFunction-), etc. Reduction operations will merge elements from the input flux into a single output signal/element, a *Mono*.
2. You map a flux from a Mono object (i.e. `myMono.map(value -> myFlux().map(values -> ...))`. This will result in a `Mono<Flux<MyValue>>` result. To get a Mono, you should use [flatMap](https://projectreactor.io/docs/core/release/api/reactor/core/publisher/Flux.html#flatMap-java.util.function.Function-), which "flattens" your nested publisher into the outside one (you can learn more about these type of operations by looking at the concept of ["monad"](https://youtu.be/C2w45qRc3aU)). Now,

Here is a simple example based on your snippet:

```java
public record Summary(int disconnectCount, int connectCount) {
    Summary() { this(0, 0); }
    Summary merge(Summary other) { 
        return Summary(disconnectCount + other.disconnectCount, 
                       connectCount + other.connectCount);
    }
}
@Override
    public Mono<ResponseEntity<?>> generateSummary(Locale local) throws Exception {
        Summary summary = new Summary();

        return test1Repository.findBySession("test")
            .flatMap(session -> {
                test2Repository.findAllById(session.getListOfObject())
                    .map(data -> data.isConnection() ? new Summary(0, 1) : new Summary(1, 0))
                    .reduce(Summary::merge);
            })
            .map(result -> ResponseEntity.ok(result));
    }
```

Comment: Hi @amanin `reduce` will do the magic!